# 'An historically accurate claim 'vs. 'a historically accurate claim'

Tags: grammar

'An historically accurate claim ' OR 'a historically accurate claim'

Which of these is grammatically correct if either one of them. They both sound incorrect to me

Comment: This question has been asked dozens of times before. In fact it's [the top most asked question ever](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=frequent). We even have a dedicated [blog post](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2011/11/articles-a-vs-an/). Please search the site before asking. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe ***a historically accurate claim*** is correct.

A [search here](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an%20historically,%20a%20historically&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) reveals that while both are used, ***a*** is used much more frequently than ***an***.